# How to Install and maintain multiple Node.js , angular-cli and npm versions in Jenkins slave

Tags: angular, maven, jenkins, npm, nvm

In our Project different branches are using multiple Node, angular and npm versions. Here we have installed these versions in different slaves. So we are restricted to run any branch jenkins jobs on any slave.

We are trying to install multiple node, angular and npm versions in a single slave so that any branch job can run on any slave, and during run time we can change the angular, node and npm version based on the branches.

I have understood that nvm will help us to maintain multiple node versions and we can invoke the required node version during run time using nvm commands.

But how do i maintain/change the angular-cli and npm version during build runtime in jenkins, or how do i install multiple angualr-cli and npm versions in a single slave.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is docker an option in your environment? If so, that could be one way of handling the problem.

Comment: No we are not using docker for this particular project.

Comment: Within Jenkins you should use global tools configuration to provide the appropriate npm/node versions etc. Also angular could be done the same way... not manually providing it on the nodes...that's bad idea...